# Microsoft Teams bot - link unfurling auth flow

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

Can't find good example of auth flow for link unfurling. I managed to run oauth flow using [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearchAuthConfigBot.cs#L111). But after user provided login and password and bot hits `OnTeamsAppBasedLinkQueryAsync` second time `GetUserTokenAsync` still returns null. So I don't follow where should I get then token from when auth flow is finished. Should I persist it somehow? Will Teams send me the token on every request or how it should work?

So in my case following code always returns null:

```
var tokenResponse = await (turnContext.Adapter as IUserTokenProvider)
    .GetUserTokenAsync(turnContext, _connectionName, default(string),
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Comment: It looks like you're passing `default(string)` instead of the 'magic code'? A few lines above your link there's a comment that says _"When the Bot Service Auth flow completes, the action.State will contain a magic code used for verification."_

Comment: Yeah, but documentation for that method says that magicCode is optional: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.botframeworkadapter.getusertokenasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable
I believe code is for kind of sms confirmation or something like that. Anyway it's not available in unfurling flow as AppBasedLinkQuery has single Url property.

Comment: So it does. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you look into [Add authentication to your bot via Azure Bot Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) and Sample code for [Bot Authentication](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication)

Comment: Yes, I read it several times. The problem is that I don’t have a dialog, I’m in link unfurling flow so I don’t have state and can’t send message. Do you mean something specific I should check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the 'state' field is not present on `AppBasedLinkQuery`. When the auth flow completes, `OnTeamsAppBasedLinkQueryAsync` will be called again and the `turnContext.Activity.Value` will contain the url and the 'state' (or magic code). We will get this field added to `AppBasedLinkQuery` (created an issue here: [microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet#3429](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/3429) ).

A workaround is to retrieve the state/magiccode directly from the `Activity.Value`  Something like:

```cs
 protected async override Task<MessagingExtensionResponse> OnTeamsAppBasedLinkQueryAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, AppBasedLinkQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var magicCode = string.Empty;
            var state = (turnContext.Activity.Value as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject).Value<string>("state");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state))
            {
                int parsed = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(state, out parsed))
                {
                    magicCode = parsed.ToString();
                }
            }

            var tokenResponse = await(turnContext.Adapter as IUserTokenProvider).GetUserTokenAsync(turnContext, _connectionName, magicCode, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            if (tokenResponse == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenResponse.Token))
            {
                // There is no token, so the user has not signed in yet.

                // Retrieve the OAuth Sign in Link to use in the MessagingExtensionResult Suggested Actions
                var signInLink = await(turnContext.Adapter as IUserTokenProvider).GetOauthSignInLinkAsync(turnContext, _connectionName, cancellationToken);

                return new MessagingExtensionResponse
                {
                    ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
                    {
                        Type = "auth",
                        SuggestedActions = new MessagingExtensionSuggestedAction
                        {
                            Actions = new List<CardAction>
                                {
                                    new CardAction
                                    {
                                        Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                                        Value = signInLink,
                                        Title = "Bot Service OAuth",
                                    },
                                },
                        },
                    },
                };
            }

            var heroCard = new ThumbnailCard
            {
                Title = "Thumbnail Card",
                Text = query.Url,
                Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/master/icon.png") },
            };

            var attachments = new MessagingExtensionAttachment(HeroCard.ContentType, null, heroCard);
            var result = new MessagingExtensionResult("list", "result", new[] { attachments });

            return new MessagingExtensionResponse(result);
        }
```